# Django Model Doesn't Delete, Page Just Reloads

Tags: python, django

I have an upload dashboard where it displays the users files.  The files are represented by a model, and there a view for the dashboard, and a second for the delete action.

Here is the model for the file upload and the related model client:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientUpload(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Client Uploads")
        verbose_name = _("Client Upload")


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Clients")
        verbose_name = _("Client")
        permissions = (
            ("can_upload", _("Can upload files.")),
            ("can_access_uploads", _("Can access upload dashboard.")),
            ("is_client", _("Is a client.")),
        )
```

Here is the url pattern for the `delete` view:

```
url(r'^dashboard/delete/(?P<upload_id>\d+)$', views.dashboard_delete, name='dashboard-delete'),
```

Here is the view for the dashboard and the dashboard delete action:

```
def dashboard_delete(request, upload_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(ClientUpload, pk=upload_id)
    p.delete()  

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))

@login_required(login_url='/dashboard-login/')
def dashboard(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = request.user.client

    files = ClientUpload.objects.filter(client=current_client)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            dz_files = request.FILES.getlist('file_upload')
            for f in dz_files:
                new_file = ClientUpload(client=current_client, file_upload=f)
                new_file.save() 
                logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                logger.info("File uploaded from " + current_client.company)
        else:
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.warning("Upload Failed")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form, 'client': current_client, 'files': files}
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and finally the section of the template for the file listing where the dashboard-delete view is called from:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Filename{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Size (Bytes){% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Upload Time{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Actions{% endblocktrans %}</th>
</tr>
{% for file in files %}
    {% with uploaded_file=file.file_upload %}  
 <tr>
    <th>{{ uploaded_file.name|pathend }}</th>
    <th>{{ uploaded_file.size }}</th>
    <th>{{ file.created_at }}</th>
    <th><a href="{{ uploaded_file.url }}" id="view-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a><a href="{% url 'dashboard-delete' file.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></th>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>   
</table>
```

In actions there is an icon with an anchor to the dashboard-delete named url.  I pass in the current files id.  And then in the url.py file I pass it in the regex.  The view then finds and deletes the file.  I use `get_object_or_404()` and get no 404 but the page just refreshes and nothing is deleted.  For some reason when I press the delete icon I get two requests to /dashboard/delete/5 (5 would be the upload_id for that file) rather than just one.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, why are my models not being deleted, the page reloads and that's it.  I cannot find what is wrong.  I tried using catch redirect with the dj debug toolbar but it doesn't capture the redirect back to dashboard from dashboard-delete view.  Which makes no sense, ordinarily it would catch the redirect.

If you need more information or need to see more code let me know and I will post it but you should have what you need to figure it out.  I've been stuck here for a week so I could really use some help to finally get his done.

I know the ID's are correct because they are in the Admin panel as the same numbers and when I hover over I see which ID each item is and they line up with the Admin panel's ID's.  I also tried doing `{% url 'dashboard-delete' upload_id=file.id %}` and it didn't work either, I don't think it has to be a kwarg in this case anyway.

I am completely stumpped here.  I've done this exact method many times and it has always worked.  What am I missing?

EDIT:

After further testing, it seems the view is never even getting called which makes no sense.  When I hover over the link I get the correct URL, but the view never gets called.  I put a logging line at the top and it never occurs.  Why would this be?  What would cause it not to be called?

Noticed that it seems the view doesn't even get called at all.  I cant even execute a log statement from inside on the first line.  Why would this happen?  I've used the same delete views before, and I even tried a CBV with DeleteView.

Comment: if you use post_delete, are you sure you still have access to the instance? May be you might have to try using the `pre_delete` signal

Comment: I had gotten that working, I'm stuck on the title of the question.  Why my delete view doesn't delete.

Comment: Do you have `@login_required(login_url='/dashboard-login/')` on top of your delete view?

Comment: No just on the dashboard, they won't see the delete view links without being logged in but I guess they could enter the URL if they are smart so I can add it.  But the thing is the id's are unique to each client (expanded user model) so I'm not sure how that works, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Adding it made no difference, but I guess I should have it anyway.

Comment: What do you have in urls.py ?

Comment: Wow if i posted it all you woulda caught it, i had /dashboard above /dashboard/delete so it was hitting the shorted regex first, I knew this and I  just forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move my /dashboard/delete above /dashboard in urlpatterns, I knew this and had forgotten.  Works now.  Stupid me.